# Interactive Powershell using Intellij Run Configuration?

Tags: python, powershell, intellij-idea

I have a python script `foo` which uses `getpass` to prompt for a password.  This python script works at the windows powershell command line:

```
PS D:\Users\me\projects> foo
Password:
```

I am calling this python script within a powershell script `bar.ps1` and everything still works fine at the command line:

```
PS D:\Users\me\projects> .\bar.ps1 -bar_argument 42
bar_argument is: 42
calling foo
Password:
```

The above works when I run the script in the Intellij `Terminal` but when I setup a powershell run configuration using the Intellij powershell plugin the "Password:" prompt never appears and the powershell script just hangs:

> C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -File D:\Users\me\projects\bar.ps1 -bar_argument 42
>
> bar_argument is: 42
>
> calling foo

**How can I run a powershell script using the Intellij run configuration and have the script work interactively (similar to the command line behavior)?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python script needs to run non-interactively, since it's called as such by the PowerShell script. Move the interactive part to the PowerShell script an pass the value as an argument to the python script.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  But why would the behavior change by switching from `Terminal` to `run` in intellij?  The python is being called the same way by `bar.ps1` but in the `run` version the interactivity drops off...

Comment: I'm not aware of intellij but I assume "Terminal" is equivalent to "interactive" (as you would type to the prompt) and "run" is equivalent to "call a script". If you call python from a script it has no terminal it can attach to, the only user interface is given to the script.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not the powershell terminal the following worked for me with

- win10
- IDEA 2019.1
- phyton 3.7.4 (installed: py launcher and associate files with phyton)

In IDEA windows Terminal execute the following command

- path

and make sure the path to phyton.exe is set

execute the script with py. It should work:

[image]